# Problema no layout dos privilégios

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Com os novos privilégios, estourou o layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso ainda acontece com você? Pra mim aparece diferente (porém um pouco estranho ainda).

Comment: Parece ter resolvido.

Comment: Revendo o problema, acho que era somente a falta das imagens.